# Spring incorrect Hibernate liquibase mapping

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, liquibase

RideController.java

```
@RestController
public class RideController {

    @Autowired
    RideService rideService;

    @PostMapping(path = "/api/ride")
    public ResponseEntity<Ride> createNewRide(@RequestBody Ride ride) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(rideService.save(ride));
    }
}
```

RideService.java

```
public interface RideService {

  public Ride save(Ride ride);

  public Ride findById(Long rideId);

  public List<Ride> getAll();

}
```

RideServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class RideServiceImpl implements RideService {

    @Autowired
    RideRepository rideRepository;

    public Ride save(Ride ride) {
        return rideRepository.save(ride);
    }

    public Ride findById(Long rideId) {
        Optional<Ride> optionalRide = rideRepository.findById(rideId);
        if (optionalRide.isPresent()) {
            return optionalRide.get();
        } else
            return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Ride> getAll() {
        List<Ride> rideList = new ArrayList<>();
        rideRepository.findAll().forEach(rideList::add);
        return rideList;
    }

}
```

RideRepository.java

```
@RestResource(exported = false)
public interface RideRepository extends CrudRepository<Ride, Long> {

}
```

PersonRepository.java

```
@RestResource(exported=false)
    public interface PersonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long> {
      Optional<Person> findById(Long id);
    }
```

Person.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
@SecondaryTable(name = "ride")
public class Person implements Serializable{

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 7401548380514451401L;

  public Person() {}

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  Long id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  String name;

  @NotNull
  @Email
  @Column(name = "email")
  String email;

  @Column(name = "registration_number")
  String registrationNumber;

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getEmail() {
    return email;
  }

  public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
  }

  public String getRegistrationNumber() {
    return registrationNumber;
  }

  public void setRegistrationNumber(String registrationNumber) {
    this.registrationNumber = registrationNumber;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((email == null) ? 0 : email.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((registrationNumber == null) ? 0 : registrationNumber.hashCode());
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
      return true;
    if (obj == null)
      return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
      return false;
    Person other = (Person) obj;
    if (email == null) {
      if (other.email != null)
        return false;
    } else if (!email.equals(other.email))
      return false;
    if (id == null) {
      if (other.id != null)
        return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
      return false;
    if (name == null) {
      if (other.name != null)
        return false;
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
      return false;
    if (registrationNumber == null) {
      if (other.registrationNumber != null)
        return false;
    } else if (!registrationNumber.equals(other.registrationNumber))
      return false;
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Person [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", email=" + email + ", registrationNumber=" + registrationNumber + "]";
  }
}
```

Ride.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ride")
public class Ride implements Serializable{

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 9097639215351514001L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  Long id;

  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "start_time")
  String startTime;

  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "end_time")
  String endTime;

  @Column(name = "distance")
  Long distance;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "driver_id")
  Person driver;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "rider_id")
  Person rider;

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getStartTime() {
    return startTime;
  }

  public void setStartTime(String startTime) {
    this.startTime = startTime;
  }

  public String getEndTime() {
    return endTime;
  }

  public void setEndTime(String endTime) {
    this.endTime = endTime;
  }

  public Long getDistance() {
    return distance;
  }

  public void setDistance(Long distance) {
    this.distance = distance;
  }

  public Person getDriver() {
    return driver;
  }

  public void setDriver(Person driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
  }

  public Person getRider() {
    return rider;
  }

  public void setRider(Person rider) {
    this.rider = rider;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((distance == null) ? 0 : distance.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((driver == null) ? 0 : driver.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((endTime == null) ? 0 : endTime.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((rider == null) ? 0 : rider.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((startTime == null) ? 0 : startTime.hashCode());
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
      return true;
    if (obj == null)
      return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
      return false;
    Ride other = (Ride) obj;
    if (distance == null) {
      if (other.distance != null)
        return false;
    } else if (!distance.equals(other.distance))
      return false;
    if (driver == null) {
      if (other.driver != null)
        return false;
    } else if (!driver.equals(other.driver))
      return false;
    if (endTime == null) {
      if (other.endTime != null)
        return false;
    } else if (!endTime.equals(other.endTime))
      return false;
    if (id == null) {
      if (other.id != null)
        return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
      return false;
    if (rider == null) {
      if (other.rider != null)
        return false;
    } else if (!rider.equals(other.rider))
      return false;
    if (startTime == null) {
      if (other.startTime != null)
        return false;
    } else if (!startTime.equals(other.startTime))
      return false;
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Ride [id=" + id + ", startTime=" + startTime + ", endTime=" + endTime + ", distance=" + distance + ", driver=" + driver + ", rider=" + rider + "]";
  }  
}
```

db.changelog-1.0.xml

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd">
    <changeSet author="crossover" id="1001122001_create_tables">
        <createTable tableName="person">
            <column autoIncrement="true" name="id" type="BIGINT">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="pk_person"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
            <column name="email" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
            <column name="registration_number" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
        </createTable>
        <createTable tableName="ride">
            <column autoIncrement="true" name="id" type="BIGINT">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="pk_ride"/>
            </column>
            <column name="driver_id" type="BIGINT"/>
            <column name="rider_id" type="BIGINT"/>
            <column name="start_time" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
            <column name="end_time" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
            <column name="distance" type="BIGINT"/>
        </createTable>
         <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="driver_id"
            baseTableName="ride"
            constraintName="fk_address_person_driver"
            onDelete="CASCADE"
            onUpdate="RESTRICT"
            referencedColumnNames="id"
            referencedTableName="person"/>
          <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="rider_id"
            baseTableName="ride"
            constraintName="fk_address_person_rider"
            onDelete="CASCADE"
            onUpdate="RESTRICT"
            referencedColumnNames="id"
            referencedTableName="person"/>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

db.changelog-master.xml

```
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">
  <include file="db/changelog/db.changelog-1.0.xml"/>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

PersonService.java

```
public interface PersonService {
  public List<Person> getAll();

  public Person save(Person p);

  public Person findById(Long personId);

}
```

PersonServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService{

  @Autowired
  PersonRepository personRepository;

  @Override
  public List<Person> getAll() {
    List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
    personRepository.findAll().forEach(personList::add);
    return personList;

  }

  public Person save(Person p) {
    return personRepository.save(p);
  }

  @Override
  public Person findById(Long personId) {
    Optional<Person> dbPerson = personRepository.findById(personId);
    return dbPerson.orElse(null);
  }
}
```

I have this following project..not made or written by me and I am trying to solve an error with this project. Basically when i try to create a ride "/api/ride" using below shared request, I always end up with wrong data being saved to database.

Request:

```
{
  "distance": 20,
  "driver": {
    "email": "testdriver@test.com",
    "id": 1,
    "name": "test driver",
    "registrationNumber": "7895612313"
  },
  "endTime": "2018-10-07T18:46:19",
  "id": 100,
  "rider": {
    "email": "csfragstatest@test.com",
    "id": 1,
    "name": "csfragstatest",
    "registrationNumber": "54564897456"
  },
  "startTime": "2018-10-06T18:46:19"
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "startTime": "2018-10-06T18:46:19",
  "endTime": "2018-10-07T18:46:19",
  "distance": 20,
  "driver": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "csfragstatest",
    "email": "csfragstatest@test.com",
    "registrationNumber": "465123167"
  },
  "rider": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "csfragstatest",
    "email": "csfragstatest@test.com",
    "registrationNumber": "465123167"
  }
}
```

Please help me where I am getting wrong here.... I don;t have much idea using spring jpa and hibernate...I am so confused breaking my head against this.. Any help is appreciated...Thanks in advance!

Comment: List the `CrudRepository` code also. There should be a method `save(Ride ride)`. Maybe in there the ids are mixed up.

Comment: @Jens, CrudRepository is provided by spring data core, you can find about it [here](https://www.concretepage.com/spring-5/spring-data-crudrepository-example#Steps)

Comment: Oh ok. Then maybe it's because your driver and rider are both person objects and have both the same id = 1. So The second person (rider) will override the first person (driver). Give them different ids and see if it makes a difference...

Comment: Yes I had tried that as well, but still it is not working...really frustrated ;(